# solving positional argument error in python

Tags: python, class, methods, arguments

I am attempting to write a program in python that simulates a game of cheating hangman, but am receiving positional argument errors upon compilation. I wrote the class and methods in hangman.py and called the play method in play_hangman.py. When I attempt to run it, it gives the following error:

`play() missing 9 required positional arguments: 'askForWordLength', 'askForNumberOfGuesses', 'remainingWords', 'words', 'wordStatus', 'printCountOfRemainingWords', 'printGameStats', 'askPlayerForGuess', and 'retrieveRemainingWords'`

***play_hangman.py***

```
from hangman import Hangman

game = Hangman()
game.play()
y = input("Would you like to play again? yes or no: ")
while y == 'yes':
    game.play()
    y = input("Would you like to play again? yes or no: ")
```

***hangman.py***

````
import re
class Hangman:
    # hangman self method
    def hangman(self):
        self.hangman = Hangman()  # object of the Hangman class

    def words(self):
        with open('dictionary.txt') as file:  # opens dictionary text file
            file_lines = file.read().splitlines()  # reads and splits each line

        all_words = []  # empty list to contain all words
        valid_words = []  # empty list to contain all valid words

        for word in file_lines:  # traverses all words in the file lines
            if len(word) >= 3:  # accepts word if it has at least 3 letters
                all_words.append(word)  # appends accepted word to list

        # list of all invalid characters in python
        CHARACTERS = ["~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(",
                      ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", "\","
                      "", "'", "?", "/", ">", ".", "<", ",", "", ";", ":"]

        for i in CHARACTERS:    # traverse list of invalids
            for word in all_words:
                if i not in word:   # if invalid character is not in word
                    valid_words.append(word)    # accept and append to list

        return valid_words  # return list of valid words

    def askForWordLength(self, valid_words):

        word_lengths = []   # empty list for possible word lengths
        for word in valid_words:    # traverse list of valid words
            length = word.__len__()  # record length of current word
            if (length not in word_lengths):
                word_lengths.append(length)     # accept and append to list
        word_lengths.sort()

        # inform user of possible word lengths
        print('The available word lengths are: ' + str(word_lengths[0]) + '-'
              + str(word_lengths[-1]))
        print()

        # have user choose from possible word lengths
        while(1):
            try:
                length = int(input('Please enter the word length you want: '))
                if (length in word_lengths):
                    return length
            except ValueError:
                print('Your input is invalid!. Please use a valid input!')
                print()

    def askForNumberOfGuesses(self):
        while(1):
            try:
                num_guesses = int(input('Enter number of guesses you want: '))
                if (num_guesses >= 3):
                    return num_guesses
            except ValueError:
                print('Your input is invalid!. Please use a valid input!')
                print()

    def wordStatus(self, length):
        status = '-'
        for i in range(0, length):
            status += '-'
        return

    def remainingWords(self, file_lines, length):
        words = []
        for word in file_lines:
            if (word.__len__() == length):
                words.append(word)
        return words

    def printGameStats(self, letters_guessed, status, num_guesses):
        print('Game Status: ' + str(status))
        print()
        print('Attempted Guesses' + str(letters_guessed))
        print('Remaining Guesses' + str(num_guesses))

    def askPlayerForGuess(self, letters_guessed):
        letter = str(input('Guess a letter: ')).lower()
        pattern = re.compile("^[a-z]{1}$")
        invalid_guess = letter in letters_guessed or re.match(pattern, letter) == None

        if (invalid_guess):
            while (1):
                print()
                if (re.match(pattern, letter) == None):
                    print('Invalid guess. Please enter a correct character!')
                if (letter in letters_guessed):
                    print('\nYou already guessed that letter' + letter)

                letter = str(input('Please guess a letter: '))
                valid_guess = letter not in letters_guessed and re.match(pattern, letter) != None

                if (valid_guess):
                    return letter
        return letter

    def retrieveWordStatus(self, word_family, letters_already_guessed):
        status = ''
        for letter in word_family:
            if (letter in letters_already_guessed):
                status += letter
            else:
                status += '-'
        return status

    def retrieveRemainingWords(self, guess, num_guesses, remaining_words,
                               wordStatus, guesses_num, word_length,
                               createWordFamiliesDict,
                               findHighestCountWordFamily,
                               generateListOfWords):

        word_families = createWordFamiliesDict(remaining_words, guess)
        family_return = wordStatus(word_length)
        avoid_guess = num_guesses == 0 and family_return in word_families

        if (avoid_guess):
            family_return = wordStatus(word_length)
        else:
            family_return = findHighestCountWordFamily(word_families)

        words = generateListOfWords(remaining_words, guess, family_return)
        return words

    def createWordFamiliesDict(self, remainingWords, guess):
        wordFamilies = dict()
        for word in remainingWords:
            status = ''
            for letter in word:
                if (letter == guess):
                    status += guess
                else:
                    status += '-'

            if (status not in wordFamilies):
                wordFamilies[status] = 1
            else:
                wordFamilies[status] = wordFamilies[status] + 1
        return wordFamilies

    def generateListOfWords(self, remainingWords, guess, familyToReturn):
        words = []
        for word in remainingWords:
            word_family = ''
            for letter in word:
                if (letter == guess):
                    word_family += guess
                else:
                    word_family += '-'

            if (word_family == familyToReturn):
                words.append(word)
        return words

    def findHighestCountWordFamily(self, wordFamilies):
        familyToReturn = ''
        maxCount = 0
        for word_family in wordFamilies:
            if wordFamilies[word_family] > maxCount:
                maxCount = wordFamilies[word_family]
                familyToReturn = word_family
        return familyToReturn

    def printCountOfRemainingWords(self, remainingWords):
        show_remain_words = str(input('Want to view the remaining words?: '))
        if (show_remain_words == 'yes'):
            print('Remaining words: ' + str(len(remainingWords)))
        else:
            print()

    def play(self, askForWordLength, askForNumberOfGuesses, remainingWords,
             words, wordStatus, printCountOfRemainingWords, printGameStats,
             askPlayerForGuess, retrieveRemainingWords):
        MODE = 1
        openSession = 1

        while (openSession == 1):
            word_length = askForWordLength(words)
            num_guesses = askForNumberOfGuesses()

            wordStatus = wordStatus(word_length)
            letters_already_guessed = []
            print()

            game_over = 0
            while (game_over == 0):
                if (MODE == 1):
                    printCountOfRemainingWords(remainingWords)

            printGameStats(remainingWords, letters_already_guessed,
                           num_guesses, wordStatus)

            guess = askPlayerForGuess(letters_already_guessed)
            letters_already_guessed.append(guess)
            num_guesses -= 1

            remainingWords = retrieveRemainingWords(guess, remainingWords,
                                                    num_guesses, word_length)

            wordStatus = wordStatus(remainingWords[0], letters_already_guessed)
            print()

            if (guess in wordStatus):
                num_guesses += 1

            if ('-' not in wordStatus):
                game_over = 1
                print('Congratulations! You won!')
                print('Your word was: ' + wordStatus)

            if (num_guesses == 0 and game_over == 0):
                game_over = 1
                print('Haha! You Lose')
                print('Your word was: ' + remainingWords[0])
 
        print('Thanks for playing Hangman!')```
````

Comment: When you call play you have to provide the 9 arguments. You may want to reconsider how you want input the data into the game state.

Comment: You don't need to pass the class methods to `play`. You already pass `self` use `self.askForWordLength` etc. instead

Answer (score 1):

Your `play()` method requires many arguments:

```py
def play(
    self, 
    askForWordLength, 
    askForNumberOfGuesses, 
    remainingWords,
    words, 
    wordStatus, 
    printCountOfRemainingWords, 
    printGameStats,
    askPlayerForGuess, 
    retrieveRemainingWords
):
    ...
```

When you call the function, you need to provide all of those arguments, aside from self, otherwise, Python won't know what the value of those variables should be.